# Highlighting a user's own questions

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

Is it possible to have the user's questions highlighted for him? This makes it easier to see when an answer of the question was edited and the question was bumped.

Here is a sample mockup design (I'm somewhat of a color blind, so it may seem that the choice of colors is strange. I apologize in advance).

This is the current view, where is my question?
[image: Current state of affairs]

Here is what I'm asking for, and there it is!
[image: Mockup design]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean; you can see the list of questions you asked on your profile. There's no need to mark them.

Comment: This was asked on meta.SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49174/questions-ive-asked-should-be-optionally-highlighted-as-interesting-even-if-no

Comment: @Zev: I am not notified when an answer to my question is edited, and if I ask a question which is out of my favourite tags I will not see it scrolling through the main page.

Comment: @Asaf I haven't used favorites much, but I gather from your remark that they provide some features that you seek also for your own questions. What features are those?

Comment: @Bill: I believe that this is a notice when an answer is given. I am not sure about edits and such.

Comment: @Asaf Well, if you want notifications like for favorite questions you can just add question you ask to favorites, no?

Comment: @Grigory: No. I want the question to have a bold color, similar to the favourite tags, to distinguish it from the rest of the questions.

Comment: @Asaf Why, actually? I thought the point of having question in fav. tags in different color is that it allows find interesting questions easier — and you can find all your questions in profile anyway.

Comment: @Grigory: Call it laziness. I just think it will be comfortable to have your own questions standing out.

Comment: @Theo: Is this better?

Comment: @Asaf: If you favorite a question, then you get the _same_ notifications as if you've asked the question: new answers and comments to the questions, but no notifications for edits.

Comment: @Theo, in response to your comment on the now-deleted answer: at your rep level, you can vote to delete answers with -1 or lower scores, which the poster of the answer was saying, since you were asking how it happened.

Comment: Eep. I hope your box did not get coffee on it then, @Theo...

Comment: @Hendrik: One more point why having a color distinguishing it from the rest is nice, to have the question pop up on the top of the page if someone edits an answer.

Comment: @Asaf: may I suggest that you edit your question to make it more immediately clear what you are asking?  "Marking up your own questions" sounds vaguely undesirable to me, even though I am not sure quite what it means.  But if I understand you correctly, what you are asking for is for the user's own questions to be highlighted in some color unique to that purpose.  That sounds eminently reasonable to me, and I would have to believe that more people would be in favor of this if they understood you better.

Comment: @Pete: Thanks. I have an apparent problem lately to get people to understand what I mean. I hope it passes soon :-)

Comment: @Asaf, there's a name for that problem - it's called, being a mathematician. I'm afraid it never passes.